# HTML / CSS : links don't work anymore

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm creating a website for a school project. But for some reason, my links don't work anymore, but I don't know since when.

In the beginning, they all worked, but after writing a lot more code, they stopped working.

Also when I hover over them, I don't get a pointer, so it looks like the browser doesn't see them as links either.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


/*************************************************************** GRIDSTRUCTUUR 

.grid__wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid__row {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -12px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid__wrapper:after,
.container:after,
.grid__row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.grid__column-12 { width: 100%; }
.grid__column-11 { width: 91.666666666667%; }
.grid__column-10 { width: 83.333333333333%; }
.grid__column-9 {  width: 75%; }
.grid__column-8 {  width: 66.666666666667%; }
.grid__column-7 {  width: 58.333333333333%; }
.grid__column-6 {  width: 50%; }
.grid__column-5 {  width: 41.666666666667%; }
.grid__column-4 {  width: 33.333333333333%; }
.grid__column-3 {  width: 25%; }
.grid__column-2 {  width: 16.666666666667%; }
.grid__column-1 {  width: 8.333333333333%; }

.grid__column-12,
.grid__column-11,
.grid__column-10,
.grid__column-9,
.grid__column-8,
.grid__column-7,
.grid__column-6,
.grid__column-5,
.grid__column-4,
.grid__column-3,
.grid__column-2,
.grid__column-1 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 12px;
}
*/

.menubtn {
    padding: 14px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mobilemenu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.menu-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.mobilemenu:hover .menu-content {
    display: block;
}


/*************************************************************** Home */

h1 {
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40%;
}

body {
    background-color: #e9e472;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

#achtergrond,
#achtergrond2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

#achtergrond2 {
    display: none;
}


/*************************************************************** Info */

#tak {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25px;
    width: 110%;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

.huidig {
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    color: #e9e472;
}

.info {
    margin-top: 20%;
}

.woord {
    color: #724f0a;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#start {
    background-color: #b7cd6f;
    z-index: -2;
}

.inleiding {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 15px;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

li:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: y;
    width: x;
    background-image: url(../images/Banaan.png);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#info .antwoord p {
    font-size: 13px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#waarwonenapen {
    background-color: #afc8ea;
    position: relative;
}

#wateeteenaap {
    background-color: #dd98a2;
    position: relative;
}

#hoedrinkenapen {
    background-color: #d0e3d5;
    position: relative;
}

#hoeslapenapen {
    background-color: #f0e972;
    position: relative;
}

#levenapeningroep {
    background-color: #d4b9d7;
    position: relative;
}

#hoeverlooptdeopvoeding {
    background-color: #c1d7c8;
    position: relative;
}

#wieisdebaas {
    background-color: #d8df90;
    position: relative;
}

#foto1 {
    width: 30%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    left: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
}

#woord1 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#woord2 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#woord3 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    width: 40%;
}

#woord4 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(4deg);
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#woord5 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#foto2 {
    width: 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    right: 10px;
}

#waarwonenapen .antwoord {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

#wateeteenaap .antwoord {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

#hoedrinkenapen .antwoord {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 120px;
}

#hoeslapenapen .antwoord {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

#levenapeningroep .antwoord {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#hoeverlooptdeopvoeding .antwoord {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#wieisdebaas .antwoord {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.info ul {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#foto3 {
    width: 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    right: 10px;
}

#foto4 {
    width: 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 10px;
}

#woord6 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(1deg);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}

#foto5 {
    width: 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 10px;
}

#woord7 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    width: 40%;
}

#woord8 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(1deg);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}

#woord9 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 40%;
}

#foto6 {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 10px;
}

#woord10 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 40%;
}

#foto7 {
    width: 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    right: 10px;
}

#woord11 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 40%;
}

#woord12 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(9deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(9deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(9deg);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}

#foto8 {
    width: 50%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 10px;
}

#woord13 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-9deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-9deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-9deg);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    width: 40%;
}

.boven {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
    right: 20px;
    /* Place the button 30px from the right */
    z-index: 99;
    /* Make sure it does not overlap */
    border: none;
    /* Remove borders */
    outline: none;
    /* Remove outline */
    background-color: #00960a;
    /* Set a background color */
    color: white;
    /* Text color */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    /* Some padding */
    border-radius: 80px;
    /* Rounded corners */
}


/*************************************************************** WEETJES */

#weetjesboom {
    height: 1000px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
}

#weetje1 {
    margin-top: 170px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

#weetje2 {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(12deg);
}

#weetje3 {
    margin-top: 35px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}

#weetje4 {
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#weetje5 {
    margin-top: 85px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}

#weetje6 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}

#weetje7 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

#weetje8 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#weetje9 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

#weetjes p {
    font-size: 13px;
}

#zwaai {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 110px;
}

#lach {
    width: 28%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
}

#banaan {
    width: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
}

#wow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    left: 150px;
}


   

/*************************************************************** Desktop */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    /************************************************ INDEX */
    #achtergrond2 {
        display: inline;
    }
    .center {
        margin-top: 40%;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    #aap1 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 60px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-left: 220px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #aap2 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 80px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-top: 290px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #aap3 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 85px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-left: 425px;
        margin-top: 600px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #aap4 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 85px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-left: 1090px;
        margin-top: 430px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /************************************************ INDEX */
    #tak {
        height: 200px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        margin-left: -80px;
    }
    #start {
        width: 992px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .inleiding {
        margin-top: -60px;
    }
    #vragen {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }


    li{
   list-style: none;
}
li:before{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   background-image: url('../images/Banaan.png');
   margin-left: 20px;
}


    .antwoord {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #waarwonenapen,
    #wateeteenaap,
    #hoedrinkenapen,
    #hoeslapenapen,
    #levenapeningroep,
    #hoeverlooptdeopvoeding,
    #wieisdebaas {
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
    #foto1 {
        width: 150px;
        top: -30px;
        left: 300px;
    }
    #infopagina {
        background-color: #b7cd6f;
    }
    .vraag {
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .kernwoord {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    #woord2 {
        margin-top: -370px;
        width: 40%;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    #woord1 {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    #woord3 {
        -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(4deg);
        margin-top: -150px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    #foto2 {
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: 550px;
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
    #woord5 {
        -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(15deg);
        margin-left: 300px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #foto3 {
        -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(15deg);
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 280px;
    }
    #foto4 {
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 150px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    #woord6 {
        margin-top: -260px;
        width: 100%;
        -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-15deg);
    }
    #langer {
        width: 80%;
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
    #hoedrinkenapen {
        height: 500px;
    }
    #foto5 {
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: 750px;
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
    #woord7 {
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -170px;
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
    #woord8 {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 300px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(15deg);
        width: 10%;
    }
    #woord9 {
        margin-top: -230px;
        width: 100%;
        width: 30%
    }
    #foto6 {
        width: 23%;
        margin-right: 600px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 300px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
    #woord10 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20%;
        left: 320px;
        top: 360px;
    }
    #levenapeningroep {
        height: 500px;
    }

    #foto7 {
        width: 250px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
        margin-right: 700px;
        margin-top: -150px;
    }

    .kleiner {
        font-size: 40px;;
    }

    #woord11 {
        margin-top: -280px;
        margin-left: 310px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(5deg);
    }

    #woord12 {
        margin-top: 260px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    #foto8 {
        width: 250px;
        margin-right: 600px;
        margin-top: -40px;
    }

    #woord13 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 360px;
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    #wieisdebaas {
        height: 440px;
    }

    .menumobile {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu li {
        display: inline;
        font-family:'Barrio', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    }

    .menu a {
         color: #e9e472;
    }

    .menu {
        margin-top: 29px;
    }

}
```

Comment: their is no code please share code

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: send part of html contains links

Comment: I've added a part of my 'info' page.

Comment: your code working well for me.

Comment: can you send your css?

Comment: I've added my whole css-file

Comment: Have you done some debugging?

Comment: How can i do that.? I've put al my code in W3c validator, and I had 0 errors...

Comment: please share HTML as well

Comment: Your code works fine with me as well, try using ctrl+f5 when you are testing the site in the browser to refresh the cache. I hope that makes a difference.